# Reunite linked agents after a split-combine block in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on a project in which the aim is to model a certain parking system. My idea was to focus both on drivers and cars side. The best way to do it seemed to use a split-combine block. On OnExit of the split block a copy of the car agent is created (I created a custom type called "person") and the two entities are linked with a bilateral link. After the split block agent "person" (Agent2) goes through some queues and delays and then gets to the combine block. On the other way cars (Agent1) are instead supposed to wait until the linked person get to the combine block to be released.

Although this first intuition about how to model the problem I still don't know how and what to code in the split block and in the wait block to make a car being released only once the linked agent "person" arrives at the combine block. The problem is about preemption as well since cars are not taken back following the line they were dropped.

I hope you can help me on this and I kindly appreciate every suggestion about it

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.